# Procedures MYSQL - Passar ou não parâmetros

Tags: mysql, sintaxe

Criei uma `procedure` para fazer o seguinte processo:
Se não digitar o parâmetro exigido, vai trazer a lista completa do que eu quero (no caso uma lista de alunos etc).
Se digitar, trará o aluno específico.
Mas ao contrário disso, ela só trás se eu digitar o `id` do aluno, ignorando a condição `IF P_idAluno IS NULL THEN`.

```
 BEGIN IF (P_idAluno IS NULL)
  THEN SELECT A.idAluno AS CodigoAluno,
  A.NomeAluno AS Nome, A.SexoAluno AS Sexo, A.DataNascimento, T.Turma,
  S.Serie, T.Turno 
  FROM tbAluno A 
  INNER JOIN tbTurma T ON T.idTurma = A.id_Turma 
  INNER JOIN tbSerie S ON S.idSerie = T.id_Serie 
  ORDER BY A.NomeAluno; 
 ELSE 
  SELECT A.idAluno AS CodigoAluno, A.NomeAluno AS
  Nome, A.SexoAluno AS Sexo, A.DataNascimento, T.Turma, S.Serie, T.Turno
  FROM tbAluno A 
  INNER JOIN tbTurma T ON T.idTurma = A.id_Turma
  INNER JOIN tbSerie S ON S.idSerie = T.id_Serie WHERE idAluno = P_idAluno;
 END IF;
END
```

Comment: tente  algo como  ... idAluno  = COALESCE(P_idAluno , idAluno ) no where , passado o parâmetro busca um aluno , passado nulo trás todos

Comment: Como você está chamando a procedure? o P_idAluno está sendo passado como nulo mesmo ou como 0?

Comment: Estou chamando a procedure de: spAlunoTurma.
CREATE PROCEDURE 'spAlunoTurma'(P_idAluno INT)[...]

Answer (score 0):

Forma mais fácil de fazer isso é assim:

```
    BEGIN 

      SELECT A.idAluno AS CodigoAluno, A.NomeAluno AS
      Nome, A.SexoAluno AS Sexo, A.DataNascimento, T.Turma, S.Serie, T.Turno
      FROM tbAluno A 
      INNER JOIN tbTurma T ON T.idTurma = A.id_Turma
      INNER JOIN tbSerie S ON S.idSerie = T.id_Serie WHERE idAluno = COALESCE(P_idAluno,A.idAluno);

    END;
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda amigo! Mas deu um problema semelhante.

Comment: qual seria o problema?

Comment: Ele não retorna nada quando eu não coloco algum parametro, entende?
Quando eu digito '1' por exemplo, ele me retorna certinho o idAluno 1 com todos os campos do SELECT. Mas quando eu não coloco ele não me traz nada. Justamente por isso que eu coloquei o IF P_idAluno IS NULL then